Dispose stream correctly in a method when it returns the stream?
I have this code in a method:
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (stream == null)
        return null;
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(memStream);
    return memStream;
}

Now, I want to make sure dispose the memStream correctly, so I changed the code to:
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (stream == null)
        return null;
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memStream);
        return memStream;
    }
}

Is this the correct way? or should dispose it in where called this method? Thanks

No, it's not correct. Whoever calls that method will get a disposed MemoryStream, because you disposed it before returning memStream. The responsibility of disposing your stream lies with whoever calls the method.

There is an implication here that you are using HttpWebResponse, which begs the question why, given it's deprecated? Why not use HttpClient?

Rule of thumb: When you return something that implements IDisposable you have a transfer-of-ownership to the caller, who gets responsible for the source and must call .Dispose() when it is appropiate (or returns the resource to his caller).

No, the second piece of code is not correct. Because you  return the stream, you mustn't dispose it inside the method. Everybody using the stream would otherwise get an ObjectDisposedException. If you want to return the stream, the caller must take care of handling and disposing it correctly.
However, since you copied whatever input stream you have into a MemoryStream and disposed that stream (which could be a network or file resource), you don't really need to care. MemoryStream has a Dispose method because it inherits from Stream, but it doesn't do anything else (except mark the stream as "disposed"). So you can just let the garbage collector take care of it.
